# Run Bat File with C having path variable

Tags: c++, c, batch-file

I need to run a bat file using the userpath variable

```
system("\"%HOMEPATH%\\AppData\\Roaming\\project\\Local Store\\update.bat\"");
```

this one doens't work, but the next one does :

```
system("\"C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Roaming\\project\\Local Store\\update.bat\"");
```

But I need the first one, to make it work to every user ... Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Answer edited)

I think that `%HOMEPATH%` expands to a directory name with one or more spaces in it.  This would explain why it worked for you once you added quotes.

Originally I thought that you needed to expand the variable yourself before calling `system()` but that was a mistake.  The `system()` command is supposed to handle a string as if you had typed it at the command line, and that includes expanding variables.

Comment: I have changed it this way and it worked ... still don't know why `system("cmd /C \"%HOMEPATH%\\AppData\\Roaming\\project\\Local Store\\update.bat\"");`